# SQL stored procedure , applying where clause

Tags: sql-server, where-clause

1) In SQL Server I have stored procedure and it has joins with multiple tables.
2) In that, UserMaster, RoleMaster and UserType table are there
3) Role Master will have the Following roles RoleX, RoleY and RoleZ
4) In User type master we have user type values like Type1 and Type2 only for RoleZ (As per requirement)
5) Now in the user table I have n number of users, and they are associated with any one of the above roles and only for RoleZ they may associated with either one of the user type

Problem:
 Now in the GUI I will get user filter with the Role and user type, and they will send more than one role for filter , if they apply filter for RoleZ then only they will give the usertype filter, how can I write a query to fetch the record for this scenario

Kindly help on this quickly

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

The parameters (filter conditions) must be variables and the use of dynamic query can be helpful.

For one parameter (filter condition) below is the example.

if(@param1 is not null)
then
begin
declare @var varchar(max)= 'select * from tablename where columnname = ' + @param1 
exec(@var)
end

if(@param1 is not null and @param2 is not null)
then
begin
declare @var varchar(max)= 'select * from tablename where columnname1 = ' + @param1 + 'and columnname2 = ' + @param2
exec(@var)
end

necessary casting should be done based on your requirements and the assignment of @var variables should change depending on the parameters dynamically.

Comment: thanks for your reply, In my case in the filter values they will send more than one role in list , the expectation is I have to filter based on both roles

Comment: @rolelist = '1,3'
@Userfilter='1'
I have a function here to split this valus so that i can apply them into the where in clause,
here only role 3 has the usertype, but i have to return the list of users with role 1 as well as list users in role 3 with user type as 1,
I want this in some kind of optimized query....

LOOKING FORWARD FOR MORE REPLAYS

Comment: Ok you have a function to split the comma separated values. I'm not clear with the second part of your comment. Does that refer to the usage of parameters (filter conditions)?

Comment: Thanks again for ur time, role 3 only has user type , but I need to get the user list of both roles how can I get that

Comment: So the role 1 doesn't have an user type (Null/Blank)?you want to retrieve the user type for role 1 too..is it?

Comment: Yeah, and both role list and user type list are SP params

Comment: If that is the case, in my answer there will be If conditions to handle nulls. If any of the parameter is null you are not going to use that parameter in the where clause. Also there should be some validation messages in the system to throw up a message                              
For eg:                                                                                              'Role List and user type combination does not exist'

Comment: Now I'm using the below query,


Select c1,c2,c3,c4,c5 from xyz 
join ab
join cd
join users u 
join Userroles ur on u.userid = ur.userid
left join UserType ut on u.userid = ut.userid
WHERE 1=1
AND ((@Rolelst is not null or @rolelist ='') or (ur.roleid in (select id from fun_name(@rolelist)))
AND (?????? how can i add the user list here)

Comment: @muthu You should consider changing your query to a dynamic query based on various filter conditions (as per your requirements) since i don't think changing the query that you have mentioned will give you the result that you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can check If.. Else to keep it simple in the stored procedure.

```
If(@usertype is not null)
Begin
//query for user type

Else
//query for role only
End
```

This can get you started

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql

Comment: I don't want to copy paste the same code in the if else condition